# how to get convert form values into request values in jsf?

Tags: jsf

In xhtml I should enter values, when I submit I need to get those values directly into concrete method without using bean class. In the sense is it possible to convert form values as request values like we give `<f:param>` to `<h:commandButton>` and them button value will become request..we get it through `MAP<String,String>` using facescontext

**face1.xhtml:**

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
        <h:head>
            <title>p:faces -- Exercises</title>
        </h:head>
        <h:body>
        <h:form>
        username:<h:inputText name="username" value="praveen"/>
        <br/>
        password:<h:inputText name="password" value="anil"/>
        <br/>

        <h:commandButton action="#{sample1.editAction}">
        <f:param name="country" value="China" />

        </h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
        </h:body>
    </html>
```

here need to get from values but I am getting null for username,password and for country I am getting as china....like wise I need to get for username and password also...is there any to get those values through `MAP<String,String>`

**sample1.java**

```
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
    import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

    @ManagedBean
    @SessionScoped
    public class sample1 {
        public String editAction()
        {
        //here I should get username,password as I enter in form

        Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
                .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
        String username=params.get("username");
        String pssword=params.get("password");
        String country=params.get("country");
        System.out.println(country);
         return "success";
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that ?

Comment: to get values into map..other way of getting form values into concrete method